# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: java, maven, testes-de-unidade, jasmine, phantomjs

Tenho implementado na minha aplicação testes unitários utilizando Jasmine e quero configurar no Maven uma integração continua para que os testes sejam executados automaticamente. Já esta funcionando, contudo está aparecendo um erro no console do Eclipse e gostaria de retira-lo, segue o erro na linha `<execution>`:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.github.klieber:phantomjs-maven-plugin:0.7:install (execution: default, phase: process-test-sources)

Tem as opções para ignorar o erro no Eclipse, contudo não quero ignorar se não toda a equipe teria que fazer isso em suas máquinas e outra para descobrir novos `m2e connectors`, contudo nenhum connector é mostrado na tela.

**Pom.xml**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <version>1.9.2</version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jsSrcDir>WebContent/public/utils/test/jasmine</jsSrcDir>
                <jsTestSrcDir>WebContent/public/utils/test/spec</jsTestSrcDir>
                <preloadSources>
                    <include>WebContent/public/utils/js/validate_utils-company-1.0.js</include>
                </preloadSources>
                <webDriverClassName>org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver</webDriverClassName>
                <webDriverCapabilities>
                    <capability>
                        <name>phantomjs.binary.path</name>
                        <value>${phantomjs.binary}</value>
                    </capability>
                </webDriverCapabilities>
                <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```